# MsBuild and MsDeploy to multiple servers with Teamcity

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy

Currently, I am using MsBuild & MsDeploy to update 1 server with the following command.

```
/p:Configuration=Release /P:DeployOnBuild=True /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish   
/P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://%system.server%:8172/MsDeploy.axd     
/P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc  
/P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /P:UserName=%system.user% /P:Password=%system.pass%   
/P:DeployIisAppPath="PATH TO SERVER"
```

Is there anyway i can update another 2 servers with the same compiled executable without running msbuild again? I am also using Teamcity to run this as a buildstep.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a way to deploy to more than one server without calling msbuild more than once.

Our process has evolved from a build file with multiple destinations hard coded to a powershell script that can read a config file for all the parameters. We just call the powershell script from Teamcity.